# How to call Get-Counter in PowerShell with a variable

Tags: powershell

As we all know we can do `Get-Counter` and than provide the path to the counter, e.g., `Get-Counter "\\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time")`

So now I want to do the same thing only then with a variable as path:

```
$myPath = "[THIS IS MY PATH]"           
$metricValue = [int] ((Get-Counter $myPath).countersamples | select -property
cookedvalue).cookedvalue
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Get-Counter : The called instance is not available    At [Path]    +            
$metricValue = [int] ((Get-Counter <<<<  -Counter $myPath).countersamples |

select -property cookedvalue).cookedvalue
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
        CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

So I cannot put a variable after `Get-Counter` for the path, but I need to do that!

Is there a solution to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked fine on my computer

```
$myPath="\\johns-pc\processor(_total)\% processor time"
$metricValue=[int]((Get-Counter($myPath)).countersamples | select -property cookedvalue).cookedvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct your command as a String like this:

```
 $metricValueString = "[int] ((Get-Counter $myPath).countersamples | select -property cookedvalue).cookedvalue"
```

And execute it using Invoke-Expression

```
$metricValue = Invoke-Expression $metricValueString
```

Regards

** fixed broken line of code

Comment: Nice trick thanks for sharing! Answer of John above is a bit cleaner so I marked that as answer.